# validate one ng-include inside a form

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-include

How can I validate one `ng-include` at a time,

```
 <form name="myform" ng-submit="validateData()" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div>
       <div ng-include="customtemplate"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="center">
       <input class="btn buttonNewRequest" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
       <input class="btn buttonNewRequest" type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
   </div>
</form>
```

I am using the two different templates dynamically using `customtemplate`, my problem is here, it's validating both template same time.

So how to restrict one template for validation at a time.

Please suggest a better way, I have no clue about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the example section here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Did you try the ng-if directive to conditionally check one template at a time.
Also please include some example code where exactly facing this issue.

Comment: Yeah tried but was from server side so issue.. I solved other way around. Thanks, @chakri.

Answer (score 0):

you should include file conditionaly use ng-if propoery it will work